# Ethernet port doesn't get connectivity from gateway, but does work from ad-hoc connection

Tags: networking, drivers, nvidia, ethernet

I'm currently running Ubuntu 16.04 on an old, 2009 Macbook Pro. The issue is that when I run an ethernet cable to the port on my router I get absolutely nothing. The lights on the router don't do anything, Ubuntu doesn't do anything, ping doesn't return, tried all the ports on the router, nothing. However if I take that same cable and run it from the same port on the router to my windows machine, works perfectly fine; lights, connection, no issue.

Additionally, I can take that same cable and run it from my windows laptop to my Ubuntu machine and pass a connection from the windows wireless card to Ubuntu via ad-hoc mode, again, no problem. I can connect to the internet, ping, run apt-get, everything.

I've tried running apt-get and updating all my drivers, still no dice. The only thing I can think of are the ethernet drivers on the Macbook pro, mostly because the network card is Nvidia. I have also tried figuring out how to update the nividia drivers, but I haven't been able to find a solid guide to that yet. Any help or advice would be fantastic, I've been googling my brains out for the better part of a week trying to find the solution.

EDIT: after running dmesg | grep -e force -e enp this is what it returned:

```
[    2.600233] forcedeth: Reverse Engineered nForce ethernet driver. Version 0.64.

[    2.665194] forcedeth 0000:00:0a.0: ifname eth0, PHY OUI 0x732 @ 1, addr 00:25:4b:d2:a0:b4

[    2.665198] forcedeth 0000:00:0a.0: highdma csum pwrctl gbit lnktim msi desc-v3

[    2.744225] forcedeth 0000:00:0a.0 enp0s10: renamed from eth0

[   42.576256] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp0s10: link is not ready

[   42.576803] forcedeth 0000:00:0a.0 enp0s10: MSI enabled

[   42.577026] forcedeth 0000:00:0a.0 enp0s10: no link during initialization

[   42.577322] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp0s10: link is not ready
```

sorry about formatting, I'm new to this and the info seemed more important than how it was presented.

Comment: The only thing that I can think of is trying to bootleg a copy of wine onto the system using a thumb drive and trying to run a windows driver software Also are you sure that you are running a Intel processor because there could be a power mac GX Series which do not have the x86 instruction set

Comment: I'm nearly positive that it's an intel series, mostly because that was a deciding factor of purchase at the time. However, I'll double check and report back if it isn't intel.

Comment: Running windows drivers under wine has, although it would be possible, no effect as linux treats devices in totally different way than windows.

Comment: I have seen many attempts but never *one* success running Windows drivers for ethernet using `ndiswrapper`. Let's start by identifying the ethernet device: `lspci -nnk | grep 0200 -A2`

Comment: NVIDIA mcp79.

P.s. I'm not in front of my machine right now, But I did write the card name down.

Comment: I'd like to find the exact details I requested and then grep `dmesg` for the interface name; enp-something, I suspect, and the driver name to look for clues as to why it refuses to connect. Anything else is guesswork.

Comment: Alright, then I'll get back to you in a few hours when I have the machine in front of me. sorry about the delay

Comment: I suspect the driver is `forcedeth`. When you are in front of the machine, run: `dmesg | grep -e force -e enp` and edit your question to add the result. Please do so while the ethernet is connected to the router. Also, be sure Network Manager is set to DHCP.

Comment: added the info to the main post

Comment: Did anyone think that maybe you are using a crossover cable? Since you can connect directly to another computer but not to the router. The USB adapter may be a GigaBit adapter, they can be used either way.

Comment: I can run the exact same cable from the router to my Windows machine and get a connection perfectly fine, so I'm led to believe its drivers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It wasn't the most elegant solution, but I did find a work around to my problem. I figured an adapter would use different drivers, basically nullifying the issues I'm having with forcedeth. Borrowed a USB to Ethernet adapter (which I can link if anyone is that interested) from work, plugged it in, booted up my Linux system, connected immediately, ran like a charm, no issues.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try the well-known driver parameter for your driver; from the terminal:

```
echo "options forcedeth msi=0 msix=0" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/forcedeth.conf
```

Reboot and let us know if you connected.

Comment: Still no connection, sadley. It is the exact same state as far as I can tell.

Comment: May we see the result of the terminal command: `dmesg | grep enp`

Comment: dmesg | grep enp returned this:

[    2.723806] forcedeth 0000:00:0a.0 enp0s10: renamed from eth0

[   44.631518] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp0s10: link is not ready
[   44.632111] forcedeth 0000:00:0a.0 enp0s10: MSI enabled

    [   44.632334] forcedeth 0000:00:0a.0 enp0s10: no link during     initialization

    [   44.632629] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp0s10: link is not     ready

Comment: chili555,

Sorry about the format again, I was trying to correct it but then got locked out.